# Which came first - definition of wave or wave equation?

Tags: waves, history, definition

In an interview, I was asked to define what a wave is.

I replied that it was a sort of disturbance which propagated.

Then he asked how I could identify what a wave would be like.

I said that the function representing the wave satisfied the wave equation.

Hearing this, he smiled and asked me,

> "Okay, tell me, is it so that first, wave was defined and accordingly
>   the wave equation was derived according to its properties, OR was the
>   wave equation first derived and then it was stated that those which
>   satisfy the wave equation are called waves - which one happened?"

I was just stunned at this and could not make a logical and scientific reply. Can anyone tell me, what should be the answer?

Comment: I suspect humans have been observing waves since we climbed down from the trees. A detailed analysis of the appearance of the concept in literature would be more appropriate to the [history of science SE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why not come to [$\hbar$](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar)?

Comment: IMHO there doesn't exist a single/rigorous definition of wave, and neither there is a single wave equation, so the question is ill-defined (apart from the fact that it is a rather stupid question to ask in an  interview...). Anyway, as @user36790 points out, this question is kind of off topic here (because it is primarily opinion-based).

Comment: Seems to me it's quite obvious which came first. The [sine function was discovered/described](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#History) by the 500's AD/CE; differential equations didn't exist until [this 1600's AD/CE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_equation#History)

Comment: Definitely off-topic, but I'd say neither.  Waves were first observed, then a model based on physical laws developed which was shown to describe waves.  I wouldn't say " the wave equation was derived according to its properties".  That implies to me an empirical definition.

Comment: The problem is that your first answer was correct, your second answer was completely wrong and at that point the interviewer was merely toying with you. You didn't stand a chance at that point. In order to identify a wave you have to look for a disturbance that can be decomposed into shapes that are changing slowly compared to the velocity with which they travel, i.e. after one "wavelength" they should look almost the same as before, but they don't have to look exactly the same and the velocity does not even have to be constant. It's a very tough question to answer and you basically blew it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the time of Pythagoras  vibrations of strings were studied in musical instruments, and the music of the spheres was a metaphysical view of the world for the [Pythagorean school](https://courses.physics.illinois.edu/phys193/Student_Reports/Fall06/J_Wilson/J_Wilson_P199pom_Fa06_Final_Pres.pdf).

> From observations in music, mathematics, and astronomy
>   Pythagoras and his constituents believed that all relations could be 
>   reduced to numerical relations

Waves were known from ancient times in the seas and lakes .

> [The history of sound](http://electricalfacts.com/Neca/Science/sound/history.shtml) is intrinsically linked to the history of waves. One of the first references of sound as a wave is found in a statement made by Aristotle when he indicated that air motion is generated by a source, trusting forward so that the sound travels unaltered in quality as far as the disturbance in the air manages to reach. Galileo is another one of the greatest contributor to our understanding of sound. He demonstrated that the frequency of sound waves determined the pitch.

It is a historical fact that mathematical equations for waves appeared after the 18th century, when calculus was invented and it was possible to correlate the regularities observed in waves to a mathematical format that would describe from sound to water waves to light. [Light was late](http://www.phy.davidson.edu/StuHome/cabell_f/diffractionfinal/pages/history.htm) in being identified with "waves".

So waves came first in the classification of nature, and then came the differential equations that could describe them accurately and predict their behavior.

One should note though that there exists a "school of thought" which sets up mathematics in the format of Pythagoras and the Platonic ideals school. Often one finds theoretically inclined physicists to attribute an intrinsic reality to physical models, which dictate the behavior of matter instead of matter being described by the mathematical formulae. Maybe the interviewer belonged to that school? That is metaphysics of course.

Comment: WoW!! You are amazing. +1 However, chronologically correct, I would say, you can't describe wave without the differential equation.

Comment: @user36790 describe mathematically, you cannot, though the  attempt  of the ancients with the lengths of strings gave numerical descriptions. With words you can.